# Windows 7 Folder contents in Jump List

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, jumplist

Is it possible to drag a folder to the taskbar (which, afaik cannot be done in normal way) and display it's contents using jump list in Windows 7?

Example: You drag the "Desktop" folder to the taskbar, and jumplist, is it's contents.

I know about applications like JumpLaunch, but I do not want to manually modify anything in order to display folder contents.